# I am trying to write the python code that can check repeat word in sentance

Tags: python

for this code i try to find if the word is repeat it will say word is "not unique" and if word does not repeat it will say word is "unique". I run the program but it showing error after i enter the sentence.

```
def isUnique():

    words = sentence.split()
    unique = {}
    for i in words:
    if word not in unique:
    count[i] = true
    else:
    unique[i] = false


def main():

    user_input = input("Enter word sperated by space: ")
    uniques = isUnique(user_input)
    print(uniques)

main()
```

Comment: Please consider reviewing your indentation and formating

Comment: In your text editor, is everything within the function un-indented, like it is in the question? (Everything needs to be indented in the question in the same way it is in the editor you use.)

Comment: Your function does not define the following variables: `sentence, word, counts, i`, and it does not `return` anything. Also, python booleans are `True` and `False`, not `true` and `false`. However, even if you fixed all these issues, and don't get an error, the code still won't do what you intend. Needs more work.

Answer (score 0):

There are loads of things causing errors in your code. I suggest at least learning the basics of how to define and call a function before trying to create one. Also you need to learn about variables and how to correctly reference them, and how to define boolean values.

The issues here are things you should have read about before writing the code.

**Issue 1: Indentation**

You haven't indented your code properly. You need to indent after you start a for loop (and everything within the for loop must remain indented. You need to indent after every if/elif/else statement, and everything pertinent to the statement must remain indented. Proper indentation of your code looks like this:

```
def isUnique():

    words = sentence.split()
    unique = {}
    for i in words:
        if word not in unique:
            count[i] = true
        else:
            unique[i] = false


def main():

    user_input = input("Enter word sperated by space: ")
    uniques = isUnique(user_input)
    print(uniques)

main()
```

**Issue 2: No argument in isUnique()**

When you define a function, if it requires an argument, then you need to specify the argument when you create the function. Like this:

```
def isUnique(sentence):

    words = sentence.split()
    unique = {}
    for i in words:
        if word not in unique:
            count[i] = true
        else:
            unique[i] = false
```

Here, `sentence` will be the same as `user_input` when you call the function. This way, when the computer sees `sentence` inside the function, it knows that `sentence` is the argument in the function (i.e. the user input). The way you've written it, how should the computer know what `sentence` is if it's not in the function argument? Answer: it doesn't.

**Issue 3: The loop iterator**

With the `for` loop, you call each object you're iterating over `i`. But then inside the `for` loop, you refer to this object as `word`. Again, how can the computer know what `word` is if you haven't defined it. This is the correct way:

```
for word in words:
    if word not in unique:
        count[i] = true
    else:
        unique[i] = false
```

**Issue 4: What is `count`?**

Again, inside the `for` loop you reference a dictionary called `count`, but you haven't defined anything called `count`. Maybe you mean:

```
for word in words:
    if word not in unique:
        unique[i] = true
    else:
        unique[i] = false
```

**Issue 5: Booleans start with a capital**

Python's booleans should be `True` and `False`, not `true` and `false`.

Now the errors should be gone, but I'll leave the rest up to you. I'm not sure that the code will solve your problem correctly as it is.

But you need to learn the basics. Before you start learning about data structures like dictionaries, you should be very adept with the use of variables, for loops and if statements, which this question demonstrates that you are not. Please learn these things.